# golang go-redis package, Why don't we use V8 to call packages when we refer to them?

Tags: go, go-redis

Consider package `github.com/go-redis/redis/v8`; its path ends with `v8`. So why, when we need to use function `NewClient` from that package, do we write `redis.NewClient` and not `v8.NewClient`?

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
)

func ExampleClient() {
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })
    // do something with rdb
}
```

Comment: There are several reasons why the package name is `redis` instead of `v8`: the name`redis` is more meaningful than `v8`;  the name reduces the code that must be touched when upgrading to `v9`, the name avoids conflicts with other versioned packages.

Comment: The "v8" is more part of the module the package resides in. Often these import parts look like "github.com/foo/bar/v7/some/package" with github.com/foo/bar/v7 being the module (including the major version). It just happens that the redis package lives in the root of the module.

Comment: @jub0bs agreed. And many module maintainers avoid the "suggested" `v1` backward compatibility headache by just renaming the module path and go the [v2 and beyond](https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules) route (as in this case).

Comment: The package name difference is not unique to modules, many packages use an import path where the last segment does not match the package name, `github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go` for example. See the documentation here for major version suffixes however: https://go.dev/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes